# ImageMagick: How to combine 200 images in pairs of 2 side-by-side (book layout)

Tags: imagemagick, append, jpeg, montage

I have 200 jpgs that are the same size. I need to combine them in pairs, putting them side-by-side.

So

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
```

Should make 2 new jpgs, one containing 1 and 2, and the other containing 3 and 4. Side by side.

Think of each image as a page of a book.

Is there anyway to automate this using imageMagick montage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [ImageMagick NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3a%22Magick.NET%22) in a .NET console application and did the following:

```
using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
            {                   
                for (var i = 2; i <= 210; i=i+2)
                {
                    var first =
                        new MagickImage(string.Format("PATH-TO-IMAGE-FOLDER_{0}.jpg", i.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0')));

                    var second =
                        new MagickImage(string.Format("PATH-TO-IMAGE-FOLDER_{0}.jpg", (i+1).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0')));

                    images.Add(first);
                    images.Add(second);


                    using (MagickImage result = images.SmushHorizontal(0))
                    {
                        result.Write(string.Format("{0}.png", i));
                    }

                    images.Clear();
                }  
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly automate this by creating a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for index in $(seq 1 2 200)
do
  left="$index.jpg"
  right="$((index + 1)).jpg"
  montage $left $right "page-$index.jpg"
done
```

The `seq` utility will generate a list of numbers skipping every-other from 1 to 200 (i.e. `1,3,5,7...199`).

Comment: This worked well enough for me, with a couple of tweaks: I put quotes around "$left" and "$right" so that the filenames could contain spaces, and I added the "-mode concatenate" option to the montage command so that the output image wouldn't have some weird new resolution chosen by montage.  (Oh, and I had to offset the starting index by one to account for the fact that my images are actually from a magazine and therefore begin with the cover page, which unlike the interior page images shouldn't be paired with anything.)

Comment: ...Oh and I needed the "-w" option for seq, to pad the index numbers with leading zeros so that they'd all be the same width like they were in my input filenames.  And then the (index + 1) value lacked that padding so I had to...  well at this point I'll just post my own answer I guess.

Answer (score 0):

In ImageMagick montage, if you rename your images with leading zeroes so that they are alphabetically ordered and put them into one directory and cd to that directory, then you can do

```
montage *.jpg -tile 2x -background white -geometry +2+2 result.jpg
```

The -tile 2x will put them in pairs together sequentially horizontally 1_2, 3_4, etc with a 2 pixel gap of background color. You can adjust the spacing as desired. You can add labels if you want using -label "%f" for the file names. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/

Comment: This seems to combine all images into one .jpg file.  The request was for one .jpg file to be made for each pair of images, rather than only one being made for the entire batch.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a workaround but after hours of research I've determined this to be the best way to go.

You'll want to **Create a backup working folder only containing the pictures that you want to merge. This technique will remove all previous filenames.** 
 **Then** rename all of your files in the following way [1]:

> Open file explorer and navigate into the folder with all your photos
>
> Select all photos (using 'ctrl+a')
>
> Find the very FIRST photo in the series and right click on it then click rename
>
> Name it something like: Myphoto (101) or Myphoto (1001)
>
> The 'space + (101)' or 'space + (1001)' is very important
>
> Hit the enter key and watch as your files are all renamed automatically
>
>
> Your photos should now be named in ascending order
>
> Eg: [ Myphoto (1001), Myphoto (1002), Myphoto (1003), etc.]

**You must do the above step because Imagemagick processes filenames differently from how windows file explorer presents them**

> *>Windows sorts names like so:  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9, 10, 11 etc*
>
> *>where Imagemagick sorts like: 1, 11, 2, 22, 3, 33, 4, 44 etc*

**After renaming**  and navigating to the (backup) folder with all your photos then you can run **this** command and imagemagick will work its magic!

> **magick montage -tile 2x1 -geometry +5+5 -border 5 *.png out@_%d.png**

The border and geometry tags can be removed if you do not want any white space,

 The **2x1** can be changed to whatever dimensions suit your needs! (Rows x Columns)


**Here are some additional configurations you can use instead of 2x1!**

> One by two montage - (1x2)
>
> One by three montage - (1x3)
>
> Two by one montage - (2x1)
>
> Two by two montage - (2x2)
>
> Two by three montage - (2x3)
>
> Three by one montage - (3x1)
>
> Three by two montage - (3x2)
>
> Three by three montage - (3x3)

Big thanks to [@fmw42] in this thread for pointing me in the right direction!

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-files/renaming-multiple-files-starting-with-001-not-1/26520ab1-823f-45b4-9661-65f17c25d4b9 [1]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and my solution was to use the Bash script posted in emcconville's answer - but with enough tweaks that I've felt compelled to post my own script here, though my answer probably isn't ideal since I'm not skilled with Bash.  Anyway, suppose your images are called "Magazine Issue 224 0001.jpg" through "Magazine Issue 224 0102.jpg".  Then your script could be:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

for index in $(seq -w 2 1 101)
do
    I=$(echo "$index" | bc)
    if [[ $((I%2)) -eq 0 ]]
    then
        IL=$index
    else
        IR=$index
#       echo "$IL-$IR"                                                          
        left="Magazine Issue 224 0$IL.jpg"
        right="Magazine Issue 224 0$IR.jpg"
        montage -mode concatenate "$left" "$right" "Magazine Issue 224 $IL-$IR.jpg"
    fi
done
```

The -w adds leading zeroes so that indices will all have the same width.  The if-else stuff allows the indices to be arranged into pairs without loss of the leading zeroes.  (I expect there was a better way to do this, but whatever.)  The echoing into bc strips the leading zeroes just for the if-test, so that Bash won't interpret them as a sign of octal notation.

Note that the sequence begins at 2; this is because my images start with a magazine cover page that shouldn't be paired with anything.  Obviously that could just as easily be 1.  Note that the iteration ends with 101 for a similar reason: The final image pair is 100-101, with 102 being a back cover image that again should not be paired.

Of course it'd be nice to automate detection of the "Magazine Issue 224 0" string or some such, but I haven't bothered to go that far since I don't have the Bash skill to do it fast and my project doesn't require me to do it often (so I'll just edit that part of the script manually like a chump).